# How to count sql from one column, and display it in two column

Tags: sql

I have a table like this:

```
    idrecord          |    date
----------------------------------------------
INC-20140308102029    | 2014-03-08 00:00:00.000
INC-20140308102840    | 2014-03-06 00:00:00.000
INC-20140310164404    | 2014-03-10 00:00:00.000
INC-20140311075714    | 2014-03-09 00:00:00.000
NRM-20140310130512    | 2014-04-02 00:00:00.000
NRM-20140311134720    | 2014-03-11 00:00:00.000
USF-20140317212232    | 2014-03-17 00:00:00.000
USF-20140321075402    | 2014-03-18 00:00:00.000
USF-20140321083137    | 2014-03-21 00:00:00.000
```

how to count this table and display result like this:

```
month      | INC | NRM | USF
march      |  4  |  1  |  3
April      |  0  |  1  |  0
```

Thank you

Comment: Which is your database? MySql, Oracle, SQL server etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT convert(char(3), date, 0) AS Month,
    SUM(Case when LEFT(idrecord,3) = 'INC' then 1 else 0 end) as 'INC',
    SUM(Case when LEFT(idrecord,3) = 'NRM' then 1 else 0 end) as 'NRM',
    SUM(Case when LEFT(idrecord,3) = 'USF' then 1 else 0 end) as 'USF'
FROM Table1
Group By convert(char(3), date, 0)
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3d694/2)

or:

```
SELECT datename(mm, date) AS Month,
    SUM(Case when LEFT(idrecord,3) = 'INC' then 1 else 0 end) as 'INC',
    SUM(Case when LEFT(idrecord,3) = 'NRM' then 1 else 0 end) as 'NRM',
    SUM(Case when LEFT(idrecord,3) = 'USF' then 1 else 0 end) as 'USF'
FROM Table1
Group By datename(mm, date)
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3d694/4)

Output:

```
    month      | INC | NRM | USF
    march      |  4  |  1  |  3
    April      |  0  |  1  |  0
```

Comment: @vels4j Yes but most probably Aboove query will support in sql server,mysql,oracle

Answer (score 1):

You'd use case to count 1 or zero depending on the string matching or not. Use sum to count.

```
select
  extract(month from thedate) as whichmonth,
  sum( case when idrecord like 'INC%' then 1 else 0 end) as inc,
  sum( case when idrecord like 'NRM%' then 1 else 0 end) as nrm,
  sum( case when idrecord like 'USF%' then 1 else 0 end) as usf
from mytable
group by extract(month from thedate);
```

The function to extract the month from the date may vary from dbms to dbms. Look the appropriate function up in Google, if extract doesn't work for you.

Don't use the name date for a column. Date is a reserved word in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
select month (date) as month,
      count( case when idrecord like 'INC%' then 1 else 0 end) as inc,
      count( case when idrecord like 'NRM%' then 1 else 0 end) as nrm,
      count( case when idrecord like 'USF%' then 1 else 0 end) as usf
    from table
    group by month;
```